# Exporting Charts from Excel

Tags: excel, powershell

I am using Import-Excel (great module BTW) to create an Excel Spreadsheet with 1 chart in it. However, I would like to export this chart as a .png file. There are lots of examples using MS ComObject but I am running on a Mac and Com objects don't exist.
I have been able to get this far in my powershell script.

```
$package = Export-Excel -InputObject $data -Path $filename  -TableName Xyz -ExcelChartDefinition $c -AutoNameRange -PassThru
Write-Host "Package is " $package.ToString()

$wb = $package.Workbook
Write-Host "Workbook is " $wb.ToString()

foreach ($ws in $wb.Worksheets) {
    Write-Host "Worksheet is " $ws.ToString()
    foreach ($excelchart in $ws.Drawings)  {
        Write-Host "Chart is " $excelchart.ToString()
    }
}
```

with the following output:

```
Package is  OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage
Workbook is  OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorkbook
Worksheet is  Sheet1
Chart is  OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.Chart.ExcelBarChart
```

Now, I would just like to know how to save this as a .png file.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/blob/master/Export-charts.ps1

It is an example, so your mileage may vary. If you have issues with it, please post that on the GitHub repo, and I can track it.

Comment: This example uses a Com object again I believe. It won't work on a Mac.

Comment: I don't know of a way to do it without COM, the charts are rendered only when the worksheet is open